# Sending time to SQL Server Management Studio table but it does not display?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am currently writing an application which involves a user being able to write the time to a database by clicking a button. The problem is that the data will be send to the database table, but it does not show the time in SQL Server Management Studio.

This is my query:

```
{
    string query = "insert into Sign_In_Out_Table(Sign_In)Values('"+ timetickerlbl.ToString()+ "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignIn", DateTime.Parse (timetickerlbl.Text));
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Signed in sucessfully" +timetickerlbl);
    con.Close();
}
```

The datatype in SQL Server is set to `datetime`.

I'm open for suggestions to find a better way to capture the PC's time and logging it in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't wrap the variable in `'` when you are setting value with `Parameters.Add()`, or `Parameters.AddWithValue()` as they would wrap if needed.
2. The variable in here would be the *value of* `Sign_In` and not the `Sign_In` itself.
3. Always use `Parameters.Add()` instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()`:

   ```
   string query = "insert into Sign_In_Out_Table(Sign_In) Values(@value)";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(timetickerlbl.Text);
   ```

**Edit (Considering your comment):**

If still it does not insert it, of course there is an error in your code, it could be a syntax error, invalid table or column name, connection problem ,... so put your code in a try-catch block (if it isn't already) and see what error you you get, it should give you a hint:

```
try
{
    //the lines of code for insert
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
   // the above line you put a break point and see if it reaches to the break point, and what the error message is.
}
```

Comment: I have carried these changes out and when submitting the time to the Database it displays    Signed in sucessfullySystem.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: 12:29:01 . The time still doesnt write to the database and no errors appear.  am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: @Johnathan it either should insert or there should be an error, error could be a syntax error, incorrect table name, incorrect column name, connection error ,... is your code in a try-catch? may be it throws and error but your code just ignores it, put this code in a try-catch block (if it isn't already) and put a break point in catch section to see what the error message is, it should give you the hint. I'm adding the code to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not contain your timestamp because you have commented the execution of your query. Presumably you added the comment because this line was throwing an error, remove the comment and share the error with us.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i ave it commented out because it displays the following error if its kept in.  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SID', table 'AttendanceApp.dbo.Sign_In_Out_Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.'Is this the reason it doesnt write to a database?

Comment: I Just made up a new table allowing a NULL value in the Column 'SID'  by doing this the date and time now appear in the database.  not to sure why, but thanks guys